# Bot Framework Orchestrator issue

Tags: botframework, self-signed-certificate

I'm trying to generate base model for MS Bot Framework Orchestrator using command

```
bf orchestrator:basemodel:get -o ./model
```

and I'm getting this error

```
self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I'm using latest version of Bot Framework components (@microsoft/botframework-cli/4.15.0) and MacOS as a development platform. I suppose there is a setting somewhere that responsible for acceptance of self-signed certs, but I don't know where is. More over, it's not clear what self-signed cert causes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, eventually when I was trying to use different flags (like -d for debug and -v for verbose) I was able to generate

Here is a solution:

```
 bf orchestrator:basemodel:get -o ./model -v
```